# How to use Scanner to read data received continously over a period of time in android?

Tags: java, android

I am new in dealing with android network requests .

I need to make a request to an api to access some data in Json format . I am able to receive data and save it in database with no problem but when I try to make multiple requests , I get errors with Scanner class ("api here supports multiple network requests").

Here is how I am connecting to the api

```
 connection = (HttpURLConnection) se.openConnection();
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND)) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), Constants.NO_MEANING_FOUND, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d("enteredtt","hellooo");
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        sc = new Scanner(inputStream);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\A");
        Json_raw = sc.next(); // the error occures here
```

There are two exceptions thrown which are

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: expected null but was com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream@4e45274
```

and `java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:879)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1394)`

The above code works well with one or two requests at a time. I also used singlethreadpool executors to make requests but the result is same .Is there something I need to follow while make severeal network requests or is it something to do with storing buffer data ? I will provide more code if needed .